# show label text, if his input(radio) is checked..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a dynamic radio button where when the radio button is selected, its label text appears but this is not working.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RGM2E/)

```
<label for="color1" style="background: #ff9999">1</label>
<input type="radio" id="color1" name="choose-color">
```

Comment: In what way does it not work for you? And yes, there is a link. Now, *why is your code not in your question?*

Comment: input shoud stand in front of label in order to have a selector able to reach the label from input:checked : http://jsfiddle.net/RGM2E/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Javascript**

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    $("label").css("font-size", "0px");
    $("label[for="+ $(this).attr("id") +"]").css("font-size", "14px")
});
```

You also need to remove `font: 14px/30px 'nexa_lightregular', Arial, sans-serif;` from `input:checked ~ label` style.

Checkout this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/RGM2E/2/)**